# Как отсортировать результат walk используя список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Подскажите как отсортировать вывод метода walk используя список. Нужно, чтобы walk вернул только те элементы, которые есть в списке

```
import os

file_list = [CHANGES.txt, ABOUT_APACHE.txt, INSTALL.txt]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\apache", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
    print(os.path.join(root, name))
for name in dirs:
    print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: `if name in file_list: print(...)`

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, то что нужно!